# Invoke-WebRequst to login web site

Tags: powershell, web, authentication

I want to use command line tool to login a site http://url/login.html
this page does not have form but have three input fields

```
        <div class="login-form">
        <div class="phone-number">
            <input id="account" type="text" placeholder="Account" />
        </div>
        <div class="code-input" style="position: relative;">
            <input id="acc_pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="height:35px;" />
        </div>
        <p id="js_acc_error" style="color:red;margin-top:10px;"></p>
        <div class="login-other">
            <input id="account_login_checkbox" type="checkbox" /> <span>Read and agree<a class="show-xieyi" style="color:#3a74ba;cursor:pointer;"> EUL </a></span>
        </div>
        <div style="display:none; margin:4px 0 0 0;">
        </div>
        <div class="login-btn" style="margin:10px 0 0">
            <button id="account_login_btn" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I used Fiddler capture the request after click submit button and replay request use curl but sometimes not work because cookies changed.

So I want to use command fill input fields and click button to replay request.How can I fill fields and click button in Powershell Invoke-WebRequest or some other command line tools?

Thanks.

Comment: I find how to fill field $WebResponse.InputFields.FindById('account')='username', but still don't know how to submit this request

Comment: Here is header information:Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
siteApiManager: false
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://20.0.0.2/site3/e4db7920330c4b3f86700d35f080c5b6/login.html?_mp_cmp_ttime=1494465642965&weixin_tel_authed=false
Accept-Language: zh-CN
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: 20.0.0.2
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: maipu_uc_request_log_name=39170; cmp_glb_param=881f0923d82e3c3feb47aa5d69e7e337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since curl can't save cookies so I found use powershell call ie and emulate as manual input

1. If use Windows 10 and IE 11, configure as this link
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/
2. Cancel checkbox in compatibility view settings

use powershell like this

```
$url = "http://web.com/login.html"
$username="username"
$password="password"
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.ApplicationMedium"
$ie.visible=$false
$ie.navigate("$url")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("account").value = $username
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("acc_pass").value = $password
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("account_login_checkbox").checked=$true
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("account_login_btn").click()
start-sleep -m 1000
$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the login button, it will probably just send some *HTTP* request to that address but with **POST** method. In powershell you can do something like this:

```
curl 'https://site/longin.html' -Body "account=john&acc_pass=1234&account_login_checkbox=false" -Method Post
```

You might have to tweak this a little bit, but it should work. Also by the way *curl* is just alias for powershell's *Invoke-WebRequest*.

Comment: I got curl : 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Also I used Fiddler capture requets, it like this GET /cmp/InnerUserAuthController.do?method=auth&username=username&password=cmljaGllM%3D&tenantId=1&siteId=3&ajaxRequest=true HTTP/1.1

Comment: Well that probably means that you really need GET method. Try something like this`curl ' /cmp/InnerUserAuthController.do?method=auth&username=usernam‌​e&password=cmljaGllM‌​%3D&tenantId=1&siteI‌​d=3&ajaxRequest=true' -Method Get`.

Comment: Is curl can save cookies for web site? I tried use curl but sometimes not work.

Comment: Well, I don't think it can save cookies. It just sends HTTP requests.